# Pivot on Spark dataframe returns unexpected nulls on only one of several columns

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark

I've pivoted a Spark dataframe, which works correctly for all columns except one, even though they're all almost exactly the same.

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
+-------+------------+---------+
|     id|       cf_id|    value|
+-------+------------+---------+
|3688634|300016666252|telephone|
|3688634|300019829932|    false|
|3688307|300016666252|    email|
|3688307|300019829932|    false|
|3688635|300016666252|telephone|
|3688635|300019829932|    false|
```

(there are 29 distinct cf_id values, but in this example only two)

when I run:

```
df.groupBy("id").pivot("cf_id").agg(first("value")).show
```

I'd expect to see:

```
+-------+------------+------------+
|     id|300016666252|300019829932|
+-------+------------+------------+
|3634121|       email|       false|
|3634192|       email|        true|
|3634216|       email|        true|
|3634319|       email|        true|
|3634423|       email|       false|
|3634749|       email|        true|
|3635192|   telephone|       false|
```

All columns work correctly except the final one displayed here (300019829932), which converts all values to null.

I've extracted the single problem column as a separate dataframe and ran the pivot function on it, which transforms all the values to null.
I ran the same function on another column, which works as expected.
Both columns have a single string for the data, and their names are strings of 12 digits (which are aliased later).
I presume it can't be due to the whole column name being digits as it works for all except one.
I've also tried collect_set as the pivot aggregate function, which returns an empty set.

Spark version 2.2.0.2.6.4.0-91
Scala version 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_77)

Am I missing something here? The titles & values are very similar across columns, and the functions applied to them are exactly the same, yet the column always returns null values.

Comment: As a new contributor, I'd appreciate it if anyone down voting could tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Can you check the DataType of this specific column after transformation ?

Comment: String type both before and after pivot. Value column is string and 300019829932 (the null column) is of type string.

Comment: Do you have another column full of `true` and `false` for which your code is working ?

Comment: I wasn't sure how verbose to be in the question, so to add a little more: The columns cf_id and value are an array of structs from a JSON file. The array is exploded with the id column, then flattened by selecting id, <array>.cf_id, <array>.value.

Comment: There are no others with true or false, no. But the data frame is keeping them as a string, rather than booleans. Although maybe it's causing some issue down the line.. I'll try making another column and see. Thank you for your replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as though the problem was due to there being true/false/null values in the column.

Somewhere in the pivot function it wasn't handling the three values for a seemingly boolean type, and nulling everything.

So, (given a table with only boolean cf_id values), when casting the value as boolean it works.

```
val castdf = spark.sql("""select id, cf_id, cast(value as boolean) as value from df""")

castdf.groupBy($"id").pivot("cf_id").agg(first($"value")).show
+-------+------------+
|     id|360019829932|
+-------+------------+
|3663762|       false|
|3619941|        null|
|3667500|       false|
|3631088|        null|
|3668712|       false|
|3661298|        true|
```

I'm fairly new to spark and SQL, so I couldn't explain why.
But in conclusion:
If you're pivoting to a Spark dataframe which will have a string-type column containing true/false/null values, the column the values come from should be cast as boolean.

Thank you @rbcvl for your help